# untar specific directory

Tags: directory, tar

tar tvf filename.tar gives me:

```
    -rwxrwxrwx 0/0          544795 2010-03-15 12:49 35 WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/bloggingstream.zip
    -rwxrwxrwx 0/0         1659095 2010-03-15 12:51 35 WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/groovyblog.zip
    -rwxrwxrwx 0/0          835642 2010-03-15 12:51 35 WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/myweblog.zip
```

Now if I try to extract only one specified file from `.tar` archive, like so:

```
    tar x "WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/bloggingstream.zip" -f filename.tar
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/bloggingstream.zip: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How is that possible, when that path exists?

Comment: It should work. Make sure that there aren't unprintable characters or unbreakable spaces or something, and that you're looking at the same archive both times. If you're sure, give us a link to the archive.

Comment: You mean in the content of .tar file itself or in file name of .tar file? How can I check that?

Comment: @branquito he means in the name of the zip in the tarball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `35` is part of the filename, so you should try:

```
tar x "35 WOO WORDPRESS THEMES/bloggingstream.zip" -f filename.tar
```

In case of "special character" problems, it is often better to try and extract everything from a `.tar` file (unless space constraints prohibit that) and delete files and/or directories that are not needed.